# Indexing in Neo4j, text or integer

Tags: mysql, indexing, neo4j

I am creating an application which uses both MySql and Neo4j. I think that listing the many nodes properties in a table will be faster at reading all those after querying for a specific set of nodes (or even before), but I am open to be proven wrong. After all finding properties of a row is what relational dbs are for.

To ensure consistency, I have created a property on each node which is the auto_increment ID in my sql table.

I wish neo4j would allow indexing a property regardless of labels but that's not the case and I struggle to understand why this is not possible at all.

Question is: do you think that the performance in neo4j would be much better if the index is on a number versus a string? I am thinking whether to drop the numeric id and just stick with node.name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You [can configure indexes on properties without referring to particular labels](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/auto-indexing.html#auto-indexing-config).  You do this by editing `node_auto_indexing` in `conf/neo4j.properties`.

If you're looking to compare simple equality, I'd guess that indexing on numbers might be slightly faster, but I doubt the difference is big enough to be very meaningful, unless the string alternatives are very large.

Comment: Thanks, that is legacy which I wanted to avoid but certainly it was not said in the question. This answer is therefore correct.

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to put an AutoInc label and index on that label with your auto_id node property.

Assuming that auto_id is the property you added to all nodes to reference the MySQL auto_increment ID column, then:

```
CREATE INDEX ON AutoInc:(auto_id)

MATCH(n)
SET n :AutoInc
```